# Problemas em recuperar o id após busca com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia a todos, eu estou com um probleminha aqui em uma busca do Laravel, já pensei em várias coisas mas não consegui resolver.
Tenho uma tabela renderizada em uma view e alguns botões nessa tabela que me levam para as funções desejadas para cada item, conforme esperado, e um campo de busca, até aqui tudo funciona normal, vai para as funcções quando clicado e busca como deveria porém, após a busca, eu não consigo acessar nenhuma das funções para o item buscado, após a busca, o ID se perde e não entra mais na url, "é só passar o id" sei que é óbvio mas não sei como fazer uma vez que o retorno da busca é a mesma página anterior, então se passar o ID na rota vai dar ruim para acessar essa mesma view por outro caminho(principal).

Segue um print da tela após a busca:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é a função de busca no controller:

```
//Pesquisar Máquina
public function machineSearch(Request $request)
{
    $setor = Setores::all();

    $resultado = [];

    $nomes= '';

    $maquina = ManutencaoMaquinas::where('descricao', $request->conteudo)
        ->orwhere('patrimonio', $request->conteudo)
        ->select('descricao', 'patrimonio')
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->paginate(14);

    $maquinaPesquisa = ManutencaoMaquinas::select('descricao')
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->get();

    $user = Auth::user();

    $userid = $user->id;

    foreach ($maquinaPesquisa as $maquinas) {
    $resultado[] = '"'.trim($maquinas).'"';
    }

    if ($resultado <> []) {
        $nomes = (implode(',', $resultado));
    }

    return view('portal.manutencao.maquinas.index',
    compact( 'user', 'userid', 'setor', 'maquina', 'nomes'));
}
```

Eu sei que poderia tentar um find(id) mas não poderia passar por rota, existe alguma outra forma de passar esse ID?

Aqui como a busca é chamada na view:

```
<div class="ml-auto float-right">
    {!! Form::open(['route'=>'manutencao-maquina-pesquisa',  'method'=>'post', 'class' => 'form-inline ml-auto float-right ', 'onsubmit'=>'ShowLoading()']) !!}

    <strong style="margin-right: 10px"><h4>Pesquisar Máquina:</h4></strong>

    @include('portal.manutencao.maquinas._maqSearch-form')
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

_maqSearch-form:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
</div>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="conteudo" name="conteudo" placeholder="Máquina..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
{{--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="patrimonio" name="patrimonio" placeholder="Patrimônio..." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">--}}
<div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Pesquisar</button>
</div>
```

Por fim a rota:

```
Route::get('', ['as' => 'manutencao-servicos', 'uses' => 'ManutencaoController@servicoIndex']);
```

Espero que tenha conseguido explicar minha dúvida e se alguém puder ajudar fico muito agradecido.

Se precisarem de mais informações estou aqui.

Grato mais uma vez.

Comment: Como está o codigo da view do include 'portal.manutencao.maquinas._maqSearch-form'?

Comment: Obrigado @JoséVeiga, eu editei a questão com o código que você pediu...

Answer (score 0):

Valeu por tentar ajudar @JoséVeiga, consegui descobrir o que estava fazendo errado.
Na verdade eu esqueci de colocar o id no select da busca...
Ficou assim:

```
//Pesquisar Máquina
public function machineSearch(Request $request)
{
    $setor = Setores::all();

    $resultado = [];

    $nomes= '';

    $maquina = ManutencaoMaquinas::where('descricao', $request->conteudo)
        ->orwhere('patrimonio', $request->conteudo)
        ->select('descricao', 'patrimonio', 'id')
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->paginate(14);

    $maquinaPesquisa = ManutencaoMaquinas::select('descricao')
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->get();

    $user = Auth::user();

    $userid = $user->id;

    foreach ($maquinaPesquisa as $maquinas) {
    $resultado[] = '"'.trim($maquinas).'"';
    }

    if ($resultado <> []) {
        $nomes = (implode(',', $resultado));
    }

    return view('portal.manutencao.maquinas.index',
    compact( 'user', 'userid', 'setor', 'maquina', 'nomes'));
}
```

Muito obrigado.